# how to fix MessageQueue leak?

Tags: android

eakcanary version:1.5.4;
androidVersion:8.0.0
API:26
Device: samsung samsung SM-G9650

- GC ROOT android.os.MessageQueue.mMessages
- references android.os.Message.next
- references android.os.Message.next
- references android.os.Message.target
- references android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.this$0
- references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mActivityConfigCallback
- references android.app.-$Lambda$9I5WEMsoBc7l4QrNqZ4wx59yuHU.-$f0
- references android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
- leaks com.tencent.wemusic.ksong.KSongActivity instance
- Retaining: 13 KB.
- Reference Key: ea1d67a2-2b78-4bf8-ae34-729527747efc
- Device: samsung samsung SM-G9650 star2qltezh
- Android Version: 8.0.0 API: 26 LeakCanary: 1.5.4 74837f0
- Durations: watch=8064ms, gc=296ms, heap dump=1713ms, analysis=690161ms
  the issue don't be reproduced.